# Simplesamlphp Authentication Login Failing

Tags: 7

I had a Drupal 7, IIS7, PHP 5.4 Simplesaml 1.14.7 setup that was working for using the simplesamlphp_auth module for login with my remote IdP.  We recently moved servers, so now I am on a Drupal 7, IIS10, PHP 7.3, Simplesaml 1.14.7 setup that isn't working.

When I test my Simplesaml via https://myurl.com/simplesaml (the virtual directory that points to the Simplesaml www folder), I can test my authentication services fine and it returns with the information I'm expecting.  If the simplesamlphp_auth module is enabled but not activated, https://myurl.com/saml_login goes to a page that says "Logon to the site."  "This functionality is not enabled yet."  Makes sense.

The issue is when I activate simplesamlphp_auth and navigate to https://www.myurl.com/saml_login - it downloads a saml_login file instead of redirecting to my remote IdP.  The file looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>POST data</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].click();">

        <noscript>
            <p><strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript, you must press the button below once to proceed.</p> 
        </noscript> 

    <form method="post" action="https://urlfrommysaml20-idp-remote.php file">
    <!-- Need to add this element and call click method, because calling submit()
on the form causes failed submission if the form has another element with name or id of submit.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit#Specification -->
<input type="submit" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="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" /><input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="https://myurl.com/saml_login" />
    <noscript>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </noscript>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Anyone have experience with this or know a possible fix?  Thanks!

Comment: Presumably your web server isn't configured to serve that file/path properly. Check the config against the old IIS configuration, particularly the handler mappings

Comment: My apologies, this is apparently a configuration error with my Google Chrome.  Firefox and IE are redirecting fine.  Thank you for your time Clive.